# Composite C1 reference to Composite.dll not working at build time

Tags: c1-cms

I'm trying to implement a console library that reads data from Composite C1 (global datatype called RSS Feeds) and then, foreach RSS feed, the application must retrieve rss entries from the "link" attribute and insert all entries into a global datatype called "RSSItem".

Here is what i've done:
1. Open the website composite Solution
2. Create a new Console Library Project
3. Reference Composite.dll, Composite.generated.dll, ...  into my new project
4. Implement the functionnality

Here is the problem: 
At the design time, i have all reference working perfectly fine, I can write my code with intellisense. But when i want to launch the project (debug | release mode), the reference to composite is not working anymore ...

"Error  15 The type or namespace name 'Composite' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

When i do a refresh in the project browser, intelisense works again.

Thanks for your help.

Best regards,
Jonathan

PS: sorry for my english, not my native language

For info: here is a little bit of the code:

```
List<MCG.RSSItem> rssItemList = new List<MCG.RSSItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   MCG.RSSItem rssItem = DataConnection.New<MCG.RSSItem>();
   rssItem.Link = rss.Link;
   rssItem.RSSFeed = rssFeed.Id;
   rssItem.Summary = rss.Description;
   rssItem.Title = rss.Title;
   rssItem.PublicationStatus = "published";
   rssItem.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
   connection.Add<MCG.RSSItem>(rssItemList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem was discussed here  - http://compositec1.codeplex.com/discussions/357939

The problem was that Composite C1 from a std. Windows application  is not supported. 
Based on this problem the feature request was created - [Refactor core parts of C1 to be used in "selfhost"](http://compositec1.codeplex.com/workitem/1271)